# How can i get multiple details from a table instead of one id?

Tags: php, mysql

How can i get multiple details from a table instead of one id, i get more data with the table with if..... more explanation and code below

```
    id  | class  | gender |         score           | date
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    1   | pry1   |  male  | ,first, first, first    | ,2019-12-04,2019-11-21,2019-11-20
    2   | pry2   | female | ,second, second, second | ,2019-12-04,2019-11-21,2019-11-20
    3   | pry3   |  male  | ,first, first, first    | ,2019-12-06,2019-12-13,2019-12-19 
    4   | pry4   |  male  | ,third, third, third    | ,2019-12-20,2019-12-20,2019-12-20     
    5   | pry5   | female | ,second, second         | ,2019-12-24,2019-12-24,2019-12-24

     ////////i selected e1view from the database /////////////

            if (substr_count($e1view, ",") <'3') 
                  {
                    
                    $last=0;
                  }

            elseif (substr_count($e1view, ",") =='3' OR $m1==='0') {
                
                  $last = ltrim(strrchr($e1view,','),',');

                  if ($last =='first') {
                        $last=1;
                    }
                    else if($last=="second"){
                        $last=2;
                    }
                    else if($last=="third"){
                        $last=3;
                   
                    }
```

i want to get the details of only the male students using
and add their scores individually.... and get the final score into a variable.
like

```
$finalScoreforallmaleStudent = 5;
```

Comment: in short you can't use `isset` to get anything other than true/false so it makes no sense to hope it will help return `multiple details` - See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Comment: Any other way to go?

Comment: `isset()` has nothing to do with this. If you only want male students, you use `WHERE` in the query: `WHERE gender = 'male'`

Comment: hello, @Barmar , I'm trying to search within a date range, i have columns for dates, as i've edited in the post sir, i'm unable to get it.  thanks in anticipation for your help

Comment: hello sir @Barmar, i have created it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62763825/how-can-i-get-data-from-using-date-range-for-querying-multiple-details-from-a-ta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `explode()` to split the string up. Use an assoociative array to convert the words to numbers that you can add.

```
$place_map = ['first' => 1, 'second' => 2, 'third' => 3];
$query = "SELECT scores FROM yourTable WHERE gender = 'male'";
// perform the query ...
$finalScoreforallmaleStudent = 0;
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $scores = explode(',', $row['scores']);
    $last_score = trim($scores[count($scores)-1]);
    $finalScoreforallmaleStudent += $place_map[$last_score];
}
echo $finalScoreforallmaleStudent;
```

Comment: i will try this, but actually, the details from the field are gotten in an array, should i post it directly here or in the code above?

Comment: Update the question if you didn't describe the details completely.

Comment: I have updated it, thanks

Comment: Why would you use such a horible format in a database?

Comment: Put numbers like your original table. Convert it to words in PHP.

Comment: but its a ready made records... is it possible i work with that?

Comment: I've updated the answer.

Comment: hello, @Barmar , I'm trying to search within a date range, i have columns for dates, as i've edited in the post sir, i'm unable to get it.

Comment: thanks in anticipation for your help.

Comment: Do you have to search all the dates in the comma-separated list, or just the last one? If you just need the last one, use `SUBSTRING_INDEX(date, ',', -1)` to extract it from the list. Then you can check the range.

Comment: If you have to search the whole list, I don't think there's any easy way to do it in SQL. You'll have to do it in PHP with `explode()`, then loop through the array looking for any match for the range. I'm not going to write the code for you. Try it and post a new question, as this is different from the original question.

Comment: Okay, i have tried posting, but the moment i post it, @Strawberry takes it down

Comment: Thanks, i will try to simplify and explain better,pls gimme some minutes, thanks.

Comment: hello @Barmar, i have created it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62763825/how-can-i-get-data-from-using-date-range-for-querying-multiple-details-from-a-ta

Comment: I don't appreciate all these comments. I have a life, I'm not your personal tech support guy.

Comment: fully working now, thanks for your support