# How can i get data from using date range for querying multiple details from a table?

Tags: php

I've been able to get multiple details from this table, using the codes beneath the table...

I know the table looks odd, but that's the available data table from the client.

```
    id  | class  | gender |         e1              |      e2                     |                d1                     |           d2        
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    1   | class1   |  male  | ,first, first, first    | ,first, first, first        |  , 2019-12-24,2019-12-24,2019-12-24    | ,2019-12-04,2019-11-21,2019-11-20 |  
    2   | class2   | female | ,second, second, second |  ,second, second, second    |  ,2019-12-04,2019-11-21,2019-11-20      |  , 2019-12-20,2019-12-20,2019-12-20 
    3   | class3   |  male  | ,first, first, first    | ,third, third, third        |  ,2019-12-06,2019-12-13,2019-12-19    |  ,2019-12-06,2019-12-13,2019-12-19
    4   | class4   |  male  | ,third, third, third    | ,third, third, third        | ,2019-12-20,2019-12-20,2019-12-20     |  ,2019-12-24,2019-12-24,2019-12-24  
    5   | class5   | female | ,second, second         | ,third, third, third        | ,2019-12-24,2019-12-24,2019-12-24     |  ,2019-12-24,2019-12-24,2019-12-24
```

Below is the code i used to get the details:

```php
$datfrm ="00/00/0001";
$datto ="31/12/2099";
$gender="male";

$place_map = ['first' => 1, 'second' => 0.8, 'third' => 0.4];
//e1view
$query = "SELECT e1 FROM eyfstb WHERE gender = '$gender'";
// perform the query ...
if ($result = $db->query($query)) {
    $finalScore1 = 0;
    $scores="";
    $last_score="";
    /* fetch associative array */
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $efind = $row['e1'];
        if (substr_count($efind, ",") >'2'){
            $scores = explode(',', $row['e1']);
            $last_score = trim($scores[count($scores)-1]);
            $finalScore1 += $place_map[$last_score];
        }
    }
}

//e2view
$query = "SELECT e2 FROM eyfstb WHERE gender = '$gender'";
// perform the query ...
if ($result = $db->query($query)) {
    $finalScore2 = 0;
    $scores="";
    $last_score="";
    /* fetch associative array */
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $efind = $row['e2'];
        if (substr_count($efind, ",") >'2'){
            $scores = explode(',', $row['e2']);
            $last_score = trim($scores[count($scores)-1]);
            $finalScore2 += $place_map[$last_score];
        }
    }
}
```

now what i'm trying to do is get a date range below to help display only the records from `$datfrm` and `$datto`

actually i tried this below, but i'm getting error:

```php
//Filter out dates between start and end date
$d1result = array_filter($d1view, function($data_item) use($datfrm,$datto) {
    return $data_item >= $datfrm && $data_item <= $datto;
});

$e1result = array_intersect_key($e1view, $d1result);
```

but now with the code i tried beneath, I'm getting more errors:

```php
//e1view
$query = "SELECT e1,d1 FROM eyfstb WHERE gender = '$gender'";
// perform the query ...
if ($result = $db->query($query)) {
    $finalScore1 = 0;
    $scores="";
    $last_score="";
    /* fetch associative array */
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $efind = $row['e1'];
        $dview = $row["d1"];    
        if (substr_count($efind, ",") >'2'){
            $dview = ltrim($dview,',');
            $dview = explode(',', $dview);
            $efind = ltrim($efind,',');
            $efind = explode(',', $efind);
            
            $dresult = array_filter($dview, function($data_item) use($datfrm,$datto) {
                return $data_item >= $datfrm && $data_item <= $datto;
            });
            
            $eresult = array_intersect_key($efind, $dresult);
            $efind = implode(',', $eresult);
            $efind = ','.$efind;
            $scores = explode(',', $efind);
            $last_score = trim($scores[count($scores)-1]);
            $finalScore1 += $place_map[$last_score];
        }
    }
}
    
//e2view
$query = "SELECT e2,d2 FROM eyfstb WHERE gender = '$gender'";
// perform the query ...
if ($result = $db->query($query)) {
    $finalScore2 = 0;
    $scores="";
    $last_score="";
    /* fetch associative array */
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $efind = $row['e2'];
        $dview = $row["d2"];        
        if (substr_count($efind, ",") >'2'){
            $dview = ltrim($dview,',');
            $dview = explode(',', $dview);
            $efind = ltrim($efind,',');
            $efind = explode(',', $efind);

            $dresult = array_filter($dview, function($data_item) use($datfrm,$datto) {
                return $data_item >= $datfrm && $data_item <= $datto;
            });

            $eresult = array_intersect_key($efind, $dresult);
            $efind = implode(',', $eresult);
            $efind = ','.$efind;
            $scores = explode(',', $efind);
            $last_score = trim($scores[count($scores)-1]);
            $finalScore2 += $place_map[$last_score];
        }
    }
}

echo ($finalscore +$finalscore2);
```

Below are the errors displayed plus one answer i'm not sure it's even correct:

```php
Notice: Undefined index: in C:\xampp\htdocs\SAP\genderresult\gender1.php on line 69

(line 69 is `$finalScore1 += $place_map[$last_score];`)

Notice: Undefined index: in C:\xampp\htdocs\SAP\genderresult\gender1.php on line 69

Notice: Undefined index: in C:\xampp\htdocs\SAP\genderresult\gender1.php on line 106

(line 69 is `$finalScore2 += $place_map[$last_score];`)

39.4
```

And my desired result is to get only values in e1 and e2  that are in the date range from d1 and d2
if there are 2 files in e1 or e2 field, i don't want it to display or map anything.

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: Can you add the desired result to the question?

Comment: Okay thanks, Updated.

Comment: ```$last_score``` can be ```"first","second","third"``` but ```$place_map``` array has keys ```"Mastered", "Attend To" ... ``` etc. You try for example ```$place_map["first"]```. There is no index named ```first``` in ```$place_map``` array.

Comment: @Onur, error in my example.

Comment: I have editted it

Comment: Please share the schema of the table.

Comment: @noam do you mean all?

Comment: I mean the `create table` statement of `eyfstb`. Also the row on which you get the error of undefined index.

Comment: ```-- Table structure for table `eyfstb`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `eyfstb` (
  `id` int(225) NOT NULL,
  `specialnum` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `e1` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  `e2` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  `d1` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `d2` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`gender` varchar(20) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=777 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;```

Comment: I assume `specialnum` is irrelevant to the question, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217516/discussion-between-noam-and-flochristos).

Comment: Okay @Dharman, but any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, change your dates from

```
$datfrm ="00/00/0001";
$datto ="31/12/2099";
```

to

```
$datfrm ="00-00-0001";
$datto ="31-12-2099";
```

then add

```
    if (empty($last_score)) {
      $last_score=0;
    }else{

    }
```

between

```
$last_score = trim($scores[count($scores)-1]);
```

and

```
$finalScore15 += $place_map[$last_score];
```

that should solve your problem completely.

Comment: Wow!, perfect! it works..... no issues again. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

You want to skip lines where there are not exactly 3 elements in the `e1` field. After the line:
`$efind = explode(',', $efind);`, add this:

```
if (count($efind) !== 3) {
    continue;
}
```

Add this in both places.

---

Another problem in the code is that when you try to compare dates, you compare strings with `<=` and `>=`. You should instead use [strcmp()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php).

Without knowing the entire content of your table, it is hard to see where the undefined index error comes from.

Comment: Here is the structure```-- Table structure for table `eyfstb` --  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `eyfstb` (   `id` int(225) NOT NULL,   `specialnum` varchar(100) NOT NULL,   `e1` mediumtext NOT NULL,   `e2` mediumtext NOT NULL,   `d1` varchar(100) NOT NULL,   `d2` varchar(100) NOT NULL, `gender` varchar(20) NOT NULL ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=777 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;```

Comment: Thanks noam, i've gotten the answer

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help

```
    <?php 
  

$Date1 = '01-10-2010'; 
$Date2 = '07-12-2010'; 
  

$array = array(); 
$range = 0;

$Variable1 = strtotime($Date1); 
$Variable2 = strtotime($Date2); 
  

for ($currentDate = $Variable1; $currentDate <= $Variable2;  
                                $currentDate += (86400)) { 
                                      
$Store = date('Y-m-d', $currentDate); 
$array[] = $Store;
$range++;

} 
for ($i=0; $i < $range; $i++) { 
    echo $array[$i];
}
  


?>
```

Comment: yeah, thanks, but the dates are many in the d1 and d2 database. i want to query them all

Comment: are you there?.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a bit of trouble understanding exactly what you wanted out of e1 and e2 - assume its just the last value in the field.  If I got that wrong, you can correct it in the function $eview.

Here is code that yields a result of 4.2 with the data you posted.

```
$datfrm = "";       // or something like '2010-01-01'
$datto = '2200';    // or something like '2015-12-01'

$gender="male";

$place_map = ['first' => 1, 'second' => 0.8, 'third' => 0.4];

// My understanding of the code is to get the weighted value of the
// last word in the column - if that's wrong, you can change this
// I am assuming you want the date that corresponded to the item you used
// for the final score, so if wrong, you need to change this.
// Also assume there will be the same number of dates as 'e's
//
// return false if bad value, or 0 if not in date range
$eview = function ($row, $ecol, $dcol) use ($place_map, $datfrm, $datto) {
    $parts = array_filter(array_map('trim', explode(",", $row[$ecol])));
    $dates = array_filter(array_map('trim', explode(",", $row[$dcol])));
    if (!$parts || count($parts) != count($dates)) {
        echo "Expected same number of parts and dates!\n";
        return false;
    }
    $date = array_pop($dates);      // Getting last date...
    return ($date >= $datfrm && $date < $datto) ?
           ($place_map[array_pop($parts)] ?? false) : 0;
    };

$finalScore1 = $finalScore2 = 0;

// perform the query ...
$query = "SELECT e1, e2, d1, d2 FROM eyfstb WHERE gender = '{$gender}'";
if ($result = $db->query($query)) {
        /* fetch associative array */
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      $finalScore1 += $eview($row, 'e1', 'd1') ?: 0;
      $finalScore2 += $eview($row, 'e2', 'd2') ?: 0;
    }
}

echo ($finalScore1+$finalScore2) . "\n";
```

Comment: hi, @wordragon, i'm trying that now, but getting error here ```($place_map[array_pop($parts)] ?? false) : 0;```

Comment: your assumptions are right, but i'm getting errors here

Comment: Hello @wordragon,  the question marks.. It's saying undefined question mark?

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217814/my-question

Comment: @flochristos You are probably not using PHP 7, which is where the null coalescing operator was introduced.  If that's the case, just get rid of the "?? false" - that's just there to flag an error if one of the words isn't "first", "second" or "third".

Answer (score 0):

You are doing

```
if ($result = $db->query($query)) {
    $finalScore1 = 0;
   ......
}

if ($result = $db->query($query)) {
   $finalScore2 = 0;
   .......
}


echo ($finalscore +$finalscore2);
```

Try to do:

```
$finalScore1 = 0;
if ($result = $db->query($query)) {
   ......
}

$finalScore2 = 0;
if ($result = $db->query($query)) {
   .......
}


echo ($finalscore +$finalscore2);
```

You have also not defined, define on the top of all:

```
$place_map = ['first' => 1, 'second' => 0.8, 'third' => 0.4];
```

Hope these resolve you error, rest result as per data and code

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't solve it.... I need the date range working kind of